# Lightswitch HTML - add image to command bar

Tags: css, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I know this is possible to do, however my CSS skills aren't the best, so could someone help me or point me in the right direction.

**What I am looking for:** (to add an image at the bottom right of the command bar at the bottom of the Lightswitch HTML screen)
[image]

the code that needs editing is in the msls-2.5.1.css file, under the tag of .msls-footer as far as I am aware, i want a static image adding on the very right, approx 8% as wide as the screen as to not distort the image to much.

Thankyou for any support on this, it is greatly appreciated!!

code that affects the size:

```
.msls-footer {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .msls-footer.ui-page-footer-fixed {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

.msls-footer-content {
    margin-right: auto;
}

    .msls-footer-content:not(.msls-footer-content-active) {
        display: none;
    }
```

cod that affects the colour of the command bar:

```
.ui-bar-a {
    border: 1px solid #456f9a /*{a-bar-border}*/;
    background: #244689 /*{a-bar-background-color}*/;
    color: #fff /*{a-bar-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bar-shadow-y}*/ 1px /*{a-bar-shadow-radius}*/ #3e6790 /*{a-bar-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/), to( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #244689 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #244689 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by updating the user-customization.css file (located directly in your project's Content folder) and adding the following additional declarations for the msls-footer css rule:

```
.msls-footer {
    background-image: url(images/ajax-loader.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

This will augment the standard LightSwitch footer style and result in the following appearance:

[image: right aligned image]

In line with your question, the above example floats the msls-buttons-row to the left; it also uses the animated LightSwitch loader as a demonstration graphic (simply change the url to point to your desired image).

If you'd like to size the image to 8% of the browser width, you can add an additional background-size declaration to the css rule e.g.:

```
.msls-footer {
    background-image: url(images/ajax-loader.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 8% 100%
}
```

To display the following:

[image: sized example]

Comment: thanks, I have got it working myself, which i shall post at a later date, however it involves the use of a customized theme... this is a lot more simple!!